# nodemon issue with debug package in nodejs

Tags: node.js, debugging, nodemon

I am trying to dubug my app using [debug package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) through [nodemon package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) and I am facing this much trouble that my required output is hidden inside the messy irrelevant information as you can see

#### Error / Issue

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
  nodemon bus emit: restart +25s
  nodemon bus new listener: start (0) +0ms
  nodemon bus new listener: start (0) +1ms
[nodemon] starting `node ./build/index.js`
  nodemon fork C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./build/index.js +25s
  nodemon bus emit: start +5ms
  nodemon bus new listener: exit (2) +1ms
  nodemon start watch on: *.* +2ms
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
  nodemon bus emit: restart +4ms
  nodemon bus.emit(exit) via SIGUSR2 +218ms
  nodemon bus emit: exit +215ms
[nodemon] starting `node ./build/index.js`
  nodemon fork C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./build/index.js +5ms
  nodemon bus emit: start +5ms
  nodemon bus new listener: exit (1) +1ms
  nodemon start watch on: *.* +2ms
  app:normal it is normal debugger... +0ms
Listening on port: 3000
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y

E:\Web Apps\RESTful API\express-demo>nodemon ./build/index.js
  nodemon bus new listener: reset (0) +0ms
  nodemon bus new listener: reset (0) +3ms
  nodemon bus new listener: quit (0) +26ms
  nodemon bus new listener: quit (0) +0ms
  nodemon bus new listener: restart (0) +1ms
  nodemon bus new listener: restart (0) +0ms
  nodemon bus new listener: reset (2) +6ms
  nodemon bus emit: reset +1ms
  nodemon resetting watchers +0ms
  nodemon reset +0ms
  nodemon config: dirs [ 'E:\\Web Apps\\RESTful API\\express-demo' ] +0ms
[nodemon] 1.17.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
  nodemon bus new listener: error (0) +106ms
  nodemon bus new listener: error (0) +0ms
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node ./build/index.js`
  nodemon fork C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./build/index.js +0ms
  nodemon bus new listener: exit (0) +12ms
  nodemon bus new listener: exit (0) +1ms
  nodemon start watch on: *.* +3ms
  nodemon start watch on: E:\Web Apps\RESTful API\express-demo +119ms
  nodemon ignored [ '**/.git/**',
  '**/.nyc_output/**',
  '**/.sass-cache/**',
  '**/bower_components/**',
  '**/coverage/**',
  '**/node_modules/**',
  re: /.*.*\/\.git\/.*.*|.*.*\/\.nyc_output\/.*.*|.*.*\/\.sass\-cache\/.*.*|.*.*\/bower_components\/.*.*|.*.*\/coverage\/.*.*|.*.*\/node_modules\/.*.*/ ] +1ms
  nodemon watch is complete +147ms
  app:normal it is normal debugger... +0ms
Listening on port: 3000
```

I am following these commands to debug my app

#### Inside index.js

```
const debug = require('debug')('app:start')
debug('debugging the app... Yup!')
```

#### Inside Terminal

```
set DEBUG=app:start // inside terminal
nodemon index.js // inside terminal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was very silly that I was running these two commands in different terminals that cause the problem

```
set DEBUG=app:start // inside terminal
nodemon index.js // inside terminal
```

be sure to run these commands in the same terminal.
Hope this will save time for someone.